# How to create verification code session between controllers

Tags: laravel

I have 2 controller which are Verify Controller and Register Controller. To access the register page, I have added a custom middleware where super admin need to enter a code to access it which means only super admin have access to the registration form.

I have build the verification code form and inside the Verify controller, I have hard coded a code to test if user entered the same code. I also create a session variable on Verify Controller to store if success.

**How my session works**

1. If I go to superadmin/register then store session as empty.
2. If it matches, store session value as success.

**Checking session**

Finally check the session on middleware using if else condition.

1. If empty, redirect to verify page.
2. If not empty, redirect to register page and proceed to register new super admin.

The problem is, I still can directly access superadmin/register. It does not redirecting to verify page.

**Verify Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Session;

class SuperAdminVerifyController extends Controller
{
    public function showVerifyForm()
    {
        return view('auth.superadmin-verify');
    }

    public function verify(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the form data
        $this->validate($request, [
            'verifycode' => 'required'
        ]);

        $code = "123";
        $verifycode = $request->verifycode;   

        if ($code != $verifycode) 
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Invalid Code');
        }
        else
        { 
            Session::put('session_val', 'success');
            return redirect()->route('superadmin.register');
        }        
    }    
}
```

**Register Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Session;
use App\Superadmin;

class SuperAdminRegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {     
        $this->middleware('checksessionvar');
    }

    public function showRegisterForm()
    {      
        return view('auth.superadmin-register');
    }

    protected function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'   => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (Superadmin::where('email', '=', $request->email)->exists()) 
        {
            return redirect()->route('superadmin.register')->with('status', "Email already exists");  
        }
        else
        {
            $admin = new Superadmin;
            $admin->name = $request->name;
            $admin->email = $request->email;
            $admin->password = Hash::make($request->password);
            $admin->save();

            Session::flush();

            return redirect()->route('superadmin.register')->with('status', "Successfull added to database. Please go to Super Admin login page.");   
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom Middleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;

class CheckSessionVariable
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $getSession = Session::get('session_val');  

        if($getSession == null)
        {
            return redirect()->route('superadmin.verify');
        }            
        else if($getSession == "success")
        {
            return $next($request);       
        }    
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::prefix('superadmin')->group(function() {        

    Route::get('/verify', 'Auth\SuperAdminVerifyController@showVerifyForm')->name('superadmin.verify');  
    Route::post('/verify', 'Auth\SuperAdminVerifyController@verify')->name('superadmin.verify.submit');

    Route::get('/register', 'Auth\SuperAdminRegisterController@showRegisterForm')->name('superadmin.register');  
    Route::post('/register', 'Auth\SuperAdminRegisterController@register')->name('superadmin.register.submit');

    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\SuperAdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('superadmin.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\SuperAdminLoginController@login')->name('superadmin.login.submit'); 

    Route::post('/', 'CompanyController@store_company')->name('superadmin.company.submit');      

    Route::get('/', 'SuperAdminController@index')->name('superadmin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\SuperAdminLoginController@logout')->name('superadmin.logout');    
});
```

**Kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'checksessionvar' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSessionVariable::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: It would probably be easiest to just write the verification code to the session, then do your comparison, redirect to the registration page if the codes match and delete the code from the session afterwards.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter what if users direcly entered the full path to the registration page? Do the page with load or we still need to declare a middleware inside the register controller?

Comment: You'll still want to protect the registration routes so only your authorized admins can access them.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I have edited my post. I have created a custom middleware to compare if session is empty or not. But it's not working right now.

Comment: You have mistakes in your middleware. `if($getSession = null)` needs to use `==` or `===`. Same with `else if($getSession = "success")`.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I have fixed the error and seems like my middleware load first which causes my page to load only the verify page. But I think I have a solution to that and it is working right now. I just remove my middleware at middlewaregroups and only put on routesmiddleware. For the session, it also working too. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably cut down on a lot of the steps you're currently doing and use a `Gate` in the controller.  The scenario you describe is similar to the example provided in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#intercepting-gate-checks):

```php
Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
    if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this method but I will try to use this. Thanks for the info :)